# Storing vector object in shared pointer throw error?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

Hi i m Storing a vector object is shared pointer and calling a print process to print it but its throw an error as **" no match for call to **"**  Below is the code

```
namespace info
{
typedef struct {
        std::string Yes;
        std::string NO;
        int  ID_NO;
} mystruct;

typedef std::vector<mystruct> myvector;

typedef struct {
        bool status;
        std::shared_ptr<myvector> shared;
} Myreturn;

}

void printmyinfo(const std::shared_ptr<info::mystruct>& printval)
{
        if(printval == NULL )
        {
                cout<<"Sorry no value exist"<<endl;
                return;
        }
        // here is print code which is good.
}


int main()
{
        info::mystruct *structinfo=new mystruct ;
        structinfo->yes="okay";
        structinfo->ID_NO=10;
        info::myvector vectorobject;
        vectorobject.push_back(structinfo);
        info::Myreturn *returnobj=new Myreturn;
        returnobj->shared(myvector)// bad how to store vector in share pointer of Myreturn structure
```

// how to fill Myreturn.shared with myvector and pass to printmyinfo?
                    printmyinfo(myvector)//bad
    }

At this line `returnobj.shared(structinfo)` error is thow please help me to fix it thanks

**how to fill Myreturn.shared with myvector and pass to printmyinfo?**

Comment: Sorry my mistake it is on Heap not a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this.

```
returnobj.shared = shared_ptr<info::myvector>(&structinfo) //
```

Also correct the last line, your `printmyinfo()` argument type does not match.

Comment: I need to use below Myreturn struct shared pointer to store vectorobject

typedef struct {
        bool status;
        std::shared_ptr<myvector> shared;
} Myreturn;

Comment: A shared pointer to a stack allocated object is not useful at all.